# Load a page without refreshing in jQuery by ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Load a page without refreshing in jQuery by ajax call?

```
$.ajax({
...
});
```

html:

```
<div class="insert">
    <form action="http://localhost/Siran-mehdi/admin/hotel/insert" method="post">

<div class="myGrid">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>اطلاعات کلی</legend>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="mediumCell"> <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="نام پکیج تور خارجی" title="نام پکیج"></div>
        <div class="mediumCell"><input type="text" name="term" placeholder="مدت" title="مدت"></div>

<div class="auto_box">
    <b class="search_hotel">
    <span></span>    
    <div class="mediumCell"><input type="text" name="search_hotel" style="float: right;" alt="<?= base_url();?>admin/" id="tour" class="auto_complete" placeholder="هتل" title="هتل" /></div>
    <ul class="list_autobox_hotel"></ul>
    </b>
</div>
<div class="auto_box">
    <b class="guide_search">
    <span></span>
    <div class="mediumCell"><input type="text" name="guide_search" style="float: right;" alt="<?= base_url();?>admin/" id="tour" class="auto_complete" placeholder="راهنما" title="ارلاین"></div>
    <ul class="list_autobox_guide"></ul>
    </b>
</div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="wide"><input type="button" value="ثبت" class="submit"></div>
</div>
    </form>
</div>
```

i not want use of plugin and function .load() only use of ajax call.
how is it?
With respect

Comment: do you want refresh the whole page or just a part of it?

Comment: and question is?? [RTM](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.ajax)

Comment: where is the question? you are just stating a fact....

Comment: Hi Jimi Jak, welcome to stack overflow!  we are going to need some more information before we can help you.    Can you post your page html?  when do you want the page to refresh?  which part of the page do you want to refresh?  and lastly, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi Jimi Jak,  Thanks for posting the html.   Do you want your entire page to be refreshed?  more then once? or when they click the button do you want a section to be reloaded?  your question is still quite vague.

Comment: hey jimi jak see the below thread given by @bhanu. I tried it sucessfully

Answer (score 2):

use Jquery html() function in success part of jquery ajax like below example

```
    $('body').html('<div class="insert">
    <form action="http://localhost/Siran-mehdi/admin/hotel/insert" method="post">

<div class="myGrid">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>اطلاعات کلی</legend>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="mediumCell"> <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="نام پکیج تور خارجی" title="نام پکیج"></div>
        <div class="mediumCell"><input type="text" name="term" placeholder="مدت" title="مدت"></div>

<div class="auto_box">
    <b class="search_hotel">
    <span></span>    
    <div class="mediumCell"><input type="text" name="search_hotel" style="float: right;" alt="<?= base_url();?>admin/" id="tour" class="auto_complete" placeholder="هتل" title="هتل" /></div>
    <ul class="list_autobox_hotel"></ul>
    </b>
</div>
<div class="auto_box">
    <b class="guide_search">
    <span></span>
    <div class="mediumCell"><input type="text" name="guide_search" style="float: right;" alt="<?= base_url();?>admin/" id="tour" class="auto_complete" placeholder="راهنما" title="ارلاین"></div>
    <ul class="list_autobox_guide"></ul>
    </b>
</div>
    </div>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="wide"><input type="button" value="ثبت" class="submit"></div>
</div>
    </form>
</div>
');
```

Comment: hi bhanu, this made my day. I tried it successfully

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=http://goo.gl/kKhWU">
```

replace 0 with any number of milliseconds for the delay in redirect and replace the url with your page url

Answer (score 0):

You could do `setInterval(load_page(),1000)`... and have load_page use $("body").load()

I've added an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mazlix/ZJPqT/) you just replace `echo/html` with the php or html file you want to reload every 1000ms. I had to pass random junk data to `echo/html` otherwise it would return nothing.... it is reloading every 1000ms you can check console.log to make sure.

Let me know if you have trouble understanding what's going on in the example. I know ajax can be really tricky at first.